# Could not set the tab titles into the top

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I created tabs with `ViewPager`. But the titles of the tabs are appearing in the center of the screen. I would like to keep the titles on the top of the screen. Please check my following xml codes and java files. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue.

This is the xml file for `MainActivity`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.bright.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Left" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Center" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Right" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The following is the xml file for the first fragment:

**fragment_blank_fragment1.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.bright.myapplication.BlankFragment1">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello_blank_fragment 1" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

The following is the xml file for the second fragment:

**fragment_blank_fragment2.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.bright.myapplication.BlankFragment2">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello_blank_fragment 2" />

    </FrameLayout>

and one more xml file for a fragment
```

The following is the `Activity` file:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),3);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }
}
```

The following is the place where I am returning the fragments to the main activity through `ViewPager`:

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int tabcount;
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int count) {
        super(fm);
        tabcount = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                BlankFragment1 fragment1 = new BlankFragment1();
                return fragment1;
            case 1:
                BlankFragment2 fragment2 = new BlankFragment2();
                return fragment2;
            case 2:
                BlankFragment3 fragment3 = new BlankFragment3();
                return fragment3;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabcount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `TabLayout` is appearing in the center of the screen is because you have the `layout_height` set to `match_parent`. The default `gravity` of the items within a `TabLayout` is `center_vertical`.

I am assuming you want the standard look and feel of tabs as per the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage), in which case the layout file for your `MainActivity` should look more like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_left"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_center"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_right"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.ViewPager android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also, there is a convenience method for setting up tabs with a `ViewPager`, instead of calling `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()`:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: i just changed to android:layout_height="wrap_content" in TabLayout. Thank u